# javascript countdown time formatting

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript countdown you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0kppf1m2/).

I set deadline time in this line:

```
var deadline = '12/15/2015';
```

It's MM/DD/YYYY format. I would like to change it to DD/MM/YYYY format.
How can I change it?

Another thing is countdown goes to minus when deadline is end.
How can I set some text like "Deadline is past." when countdown ends?

**javascript**

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.now();
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}


var deadline = '12/15/2015';

initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

**html**

```
<div id="clockdiv">

    <span class="days"></span>
    Days


    <span class="hours"></span>
    Hours


    <span class="minutes"></span>
    Minutes


    <span class="seconds"></span>
    Seconds

</div>
```

**jsfiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/0kppf1m2/

Comment: put a `return` after `clearInterval(timeinterval);`. at least the countdown wont update itself after the deadline. for the rest of the work, you can do a little bit of research.

Comment: thanks for showing me a way. I changed my code to     `if (t.total <= 0) {
      var timesup = "Time is up";
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
      return "timesup";
    }` but it didn't work. what i did wrong when i'm returning?

Comment: sorry, forget about what i just said, i miss read your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Create a second div for displaying the message for "Deadline is past" and when the time is over set it to visible and set the clock to hidden as in [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/0kppf1m2/embedded/result/)

html:

```
<div id="timeIsNow" class="hidden-div">
  Deadline is past
</div>

<div id="clockdiv" class="visible-div">

  <span class="days"></span> Days


  <span class="hours"></span> Hours


  <span class="minutes"></span> Minutes


  <span class="seconds"></span> Seconds

</div>
```

js:

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.now();
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      document.getElementById("clockdiv").className = "hidden-div";
      document.getElementById("timeIsNow").className = "visible-div";
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
      return true;
    }

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}


var deadline = '2015-12-14T20:14:00+02:00';

initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

css:

```
.hidden-div {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.visible-div {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

2) To convert a date from DDMMYYY to MMDDYYY use this function:

```
var d1 = "15/12/2015"
d1 = d1.split('/');
var d2 = d1[1]+'/'+d1[0]+'/'+d1[2];
```

Comment: the thing is i will fetch the date from the database. like `$r[deadline]` and in datebase it's added like DD/MM/YYYY so i'm not sure if this convertDate function works for me. I also added the function into the javascript code but i coun't make it work. Thanks for helping.

Comment: So if i got you right, you want the opposite conversion?

Comment: all i'm trying to do is make `var deadline = '(15/12/2015)';` like that. actually it will be like: `$r[deadline] = 15/12/2015` and `var deadline = '(<?php echo "$r[deadline]; ?>)';`

Comment: Matar, I think opposite conversion will gonna help me.

Comment: You're right Sorry, you can see it now in the answer itself (not in comments)

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code a little bit.

You have to clear the interval after you reached the deadline and change the `innerHTML` of the clock's container.

```
function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clock.innerHTML = 'time is up';
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0kppf1m2/3/)

And there are many ways you can create a `Date` object.
I'd suggest using `new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`.  More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).